# checkPrime function returns incorrect values

Tags: javascript

```js
numbers = [];
for (x = 1; x <= 1e4; x++) {
  numbers.push(x)
}
//console.log(numbers)

function checkPrime(num) {
  if (num == 1 || num == 0) {
    return 'It is a separate case'
  }
  if (num == 2) {
    return num + ' is prime'
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num in numbers) {
      if (num % i === 0) return num + ' is not prime';
      else {
        return num + ' is prime';
      }
      return num !== 1;
    } else {
      return num + ' is not in range';
    }
  }

}
console.log(checkPrime(27));
```

Hi. 
In the above code, I tried to create a function which returns information about whether a number is prime or not.

However, it fails in some cases. Like eg. in the case of 27 or 145, it returns the values are prime, which obviously is false. How can I amend this program to make it work?

Also, what is the smartest way of merging the case for number 2 and the rest prime numbers?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is too basic, I could not find the right answer anywhere else.

Comment: `if (num % i === 0) return num + ' is not prime';
      else {
        return num + ' is prime';
      }`  This means you return right away after checking num against the first value of `i`, while you would need to validate all values of the loop. If the number can be divided by *any* the valued of `i`, it is not a prime.

Comment: Btw, I don't know what this `numbers` is supposed to do, but it seems very inefficient. First of all, you could do that check outside of the loop (since numbers or num don't change anyway), but more importantly, you can just check `if (num >= 1 && num <= 1e4)` without building an array with the whole range. But this is just an optimization...

Comment: Other simple optimizations you could do is to let `i` run only from 2 to `num / 2`, and to early exit on some conditions, like num being an even number. Anyway, I digress; the issue is mentioned in the first comment. I'd solve that first before making optimizations.

Comment: @GolezTrol some further trivial optimizations i+=2 to skip even numbers, and actually it is easy to show that it sufficient to check up to i < sqrt(num), but that is largely irrelevant to the question. :)

Comment: Yes. But only skip the even `i`s if you early exited on num being even, otherwise the function would consider 4 and 8 prime numbers.

Comment: @GolezTrol thanks for this comment with the whole numbers thing. I used your advice and deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten the code to provide the right answer

```js
numbers = [];
for (x = 1; x <= 1e4; x++) {
  numbers.push(x)
}
//console.log(numbers)

function checkPrime(num) {
  if (num == 1 || num == 0) {
    return 'It is a separate case'
  }
  // check this condition outside the loop
  if (!(num in numbers)) {
    return num + ' is not in range';
  }
  if (num == 2) {
    return num + ' is prime'
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return num + ' is not prime';
    }
  }
  return num + ' is prime';

}

console.log(checkPrime(27));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the 'else' clause that states the number is prime before having finished to check all numbers until itself -1.

To be optimal, you don't need to loop until the number ( < num). Just until the square root of the number. (even better than looping until num/2) For example : 167 can be seen that is prime when the loop has reached 13. 13*13 = 169 > 167 so you can stop and safely afirm that 167 is prime.

For number 2 it is correct to have a sepparate case.

Below is the code for checking a single value if it is prime:

```js
function checkPrime(num) {
  if (num == 1 || num === 0) {
    return 'It is a separate case'
  }
  if (num == 2) {
    return num + ' is prime'
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) return num + ' is not prime';
  }
  return num + ' is prime';
}
alert(checkPrime(27));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code and made a couple of changes.

The reason you were having your problem is that you were returning in the for loop meaning all odd numbers would declare themselves as prime numbers.

I've fixed this but also I've I rearranged things a little, to be as efficient as possible it's good to bail as soon as possible so I do a couple of checks to bail initially I check if the number is in range, if not bail.

I've commented the code so it makes sense but if you don't understand why I've done something feel free to ask.

```js
// make an array of all numbers between 0 and 10000
numbers = [];
for (x = 0; x <= 1e4; x++) {
  numbers.push(x)
}

function checkPrime(num) {
  // return if input number is not in numbers array
  if (numbers.indexOf(num) == -1) return num + ' is not in range'

  // return if number is 0 or 1
  if (num <= 1) return 'It is a separate case'

  // check all numbers between 2 and input number
  // return if any number devides neatly
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if (num % i === 0) return num + ' is not prime';

  // if you get this far it's prime
  return num + ' is prime';
}

console.log(checkPrime(27));
```

Personally, for the range, I wouldn't have an array of all the values but I've left this in just in case there was some other reasoning we don't know about.

**EDIT:**

As you've said the initial array is not important I've remade the code to work without it, I've not included comments this time (to save space) but that code does the same thing and is mostly unchanged.

```js
function checkPrime(num) {
  if (num < 0 || num > 1e4) return num + ' is not in range'
  if (num <= 1) return 'It is a separate case'
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if (num % i === 0) return num + ' is not prime';
  return num + ' is prime';
}

console.log(checkPrime(27));
```

Anyway, I hope you find this helpful

Comment: Yes, I agree, I deleted this array. It's my first (semi)serious JS program and I wanted it to be clear for me :)

Comment: If you wan to bail as soon as possible, maybe it's better to do the easy checks (0, 1, maybe 2) first, and then check `numbers.indexOf`. Even though it's roughly the same amount of code for you, the programmer, a simple check against a number is way easier for the computer to handle than traversing the entire array, so when optimizing, take that kind of decisions into account as well. Completely eliminating it is in this specific case indeed the best way, though.